# How to choose appropriate analyzer in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-emr

I have a requirement where in I need to perform search with follwing criteria's.

1]Case insensitive match
2]Special characters match

3]Partial matches

I am using "ngram filter" as follows , which satisfies all above needs
However I will be indexing a very huge data that will have fields like "comments","descriptions" etc. which might have length upto 150 words.
From references from web I think using "ngram" filter will cause heavy disk space usage.
Is there any alternative to meet above requirements

```
{
        "template": "*",
        "settings": {
            "analysis": {
                "filter": {
                    "ngram_filter": {
                        "type": "ngram",
                        "min_gram": 1,
                        "max_gram": 25
                    }
                },
                "analyzer": {
                    "case_insensitive": {
                        "tokenizer": "whitespace",
                        "filter": [
                            "ngram_filter",
                            "lowercase"
                        ]
                    },
                    "search_analyzer": {
                        "type": "custom",
                        "tokenizer": "whitespace",
                        "filter": "lowercase"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "mappings": {
            "incidents": {
                "dynamic_templates": [
                    {
                        "strings": {
                            "match_mapping_type": "string",
                            "mapping": {
                                "type": "string",
                                "fields": {
                                    "keyword": {
                                        "type": "keyword",
                                        "ignore_above": 256
                                    }
                                },
                                "analyzer": "case_insensitive",
                                "search_analyzer": "search_analyzer"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that search performance is also critical, in this case you have to use ngrams. But you can try to reduce minimal ngram size. For example, if it's ok skip matching by one or two letters, you can set `min_gram` to `3` or even greater. It will slightly reduce the disk usage.

It's also possible to use `wildcard` or `query_string` query for partial match. The first one is case-sensitive, the second one is not. In this case you won't have disk usage overhead but it will significantly reduce the performance.

It's often a tradeoff between search speed and disk usage. Usually it's better to do a proper pre-indexing (n-gram approach) to achieve a required performance

Comment: Thanks Random ! , I tried using wildcard for partial matching but match was case sensitive hence couldn't use it.
Can we use ngram filter for fields which contains approximately 150-200 words.

Comment: You can also try `query_string` query. But for performance reasons it's better to keep using n-grams. It shouldn't bring too much overhead since they are also tokens and not unique. So, the token itself is only stored once. And token entries are stored as references, not as entire strings

Comment: I have posted another question with the same context can you please help here ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44300200/elasticsearch-can-we-apply-both-n-gram-and-language-analyzers-during-indexing

Comment: Will take a look. BTW, why you don't accept answer to this question?

Comment: Thank you @Random, I have accepted the earlier answer