# ElasticSearch : Can we apply both n-gram and language analyzers during indexing

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

Thanks a lot @Random , I have modified the mapping as follows. For testing I have used "movie" as my type for indexing.
Note: I have added search_analyzer also. I was not getting proper results without that.
However I have following doubts for using search_analyzer.

1] Can we use custom search_analyzer in case of language analyzers ?
2] am I getting all the results due to n-gram analyzer I have used and not due to english analyzer?

```
{
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "analyzer": {
                "english_ngram": {
                    "type": "custom",
                    "filter": [
                        "english_possessive_stemmer",
                        "lowercase",
                        "english_stop",
                        "english_stemmer",
                        "ngram_filter"
                    ],
                    "tokenizer": "whitespace"
                },
                "search_analyzer":{
                    "type": "custom",
                    "tokenizer": "whitespace",
                    "filter": "lowercase"
                }
            },
            "filter": {
                "english_stop": {
                    "type": "stop"
                },
                "english_stemmer": {
                    "type": "stemmer",
                    "language": "english"
                },
                "english_possessive_stemmer": {
                    "type": "stemmer",
                    "language": "possessive_english"
                },
                "ngram_filter": {
                    "type": "ngram",
                    "min_gram": 1,
                    "max_gram": 25
                }
            }
        }
    },
      "mappings": {
    "movie": {
      "properties": {
        "title": {
          "type": "string",
          "fields": {
            "en": {
              "type":     "string",
              "analyzer": "english_ngram",
              "search_analyzer": "search_analyzer"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Update :**

Using search analyzer also is not working consistently.and need more help with this.Updating question with my findings.

I used following mapping as suggested (Note: This mapping does not use search analyzer), for simplicity lets consider only English analyzer.

```
{
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "analyzer": {
                "english_ngram": {
                    "type": "custom",
                    "filter": [
                        "english_possessive_stemmer",
                        "lowercase",
                        "english_stop",
                        "english_stemmer",
                        "ngram_filter"
                    ],
                    "tokenizer": "standard"
                }
            },
            "filter": {
                "english_stop": {
                    "type": "stop"
                },
                "english_stemmer": {
                    "type": "stemmer",
                    "language": "english"
                },
                "english_possessive_stemmer": {
                    "type": "stemmer",
                    "language": "possessive_english"
                },
                "ngram_filter": {
                    "type": "edge_ngram",
                    "min_gram": 1,
                    "max_gram": 25
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Created index:

PUT http://localhost:9200/movies/movie/1

```
{"title":"$peci@l movie"}
```

Tried following query:

```
GET http://localhost:9200/movies/movie/_search

    {
        "query": {
            "multi_match": {
                "query": "$peci mov",
                "fields": ["title"],
                "operator": "and"
            }
            }
        }
    }
```

I got no results for this, am I doing anything wrong ?
I am trying to get results for:

```
1] Special characters
2] Partial matches
3] Space separated partial and full words
```

Thanks again !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom analyzer based on language analyzers. The only difference is that you add your `ngram_filter` token filter to the end of the chain. In this case you first get language-stemmed tokens (default chain) that converted to edge ngrams in the end (your filter). You can find the implementation of language analyzers here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-lang-analyzer.html#english-analyzer in order to override them. Here is an example of this change for english language:

```
{
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "analyzer": {
                "english_ngram": {
                    "type": "custom",
                    "filter": [
                        "english_possessive_stemmer",
                        "lowercase",
                        "english_stop",
                        "english_stemmer",
                        "ngram_filter"
                    ],
                    "tokenizer": "standard"
                }
            },
            "filter": {
                "english_stop": {
                    "type": "stop"
                },
                "english_stemmer": {
                    "type": "stemmer",
                    "language": "english"
                },
                "english_possessive_stemmer": {
                    "type": "stemmer",
                    "language": "possessive_english"
                },
                "ngram_filter": {
                    "type": "edge_ngram",
                    "min_gram": 1,
                    "max_gram": 25
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

To support special characters you can try to use `whitespace` tokenizer instead of `standard`. In this case these characters will be part of your tokens:

```
{
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "analyzer": {
                "english_ngram": {
                    "type": "custom",
                    "filter": [
                        "english_possessive_stemmer",
                        "lowercase",
                        "english_stop",
                        "english_stemmer",
                        "ngram_filter"
                    ],
                    "tokenizer": "whitespace"
                }
            },
            "filter": {
                "english_stop": {
                    "type": "stop"
                },
                "english_stemmer": {
                    "type": "stemmer",
                    "language": "english"
                },
                "english_possessive_stemmer": {
                    "type": "stemmer",
                    "language": "possessive_english"
                },
                "ngram_filter": {
                    "type": "edge_ngram",
                    "min_gram": 1,
                    "max_gram": 25
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Random , your answer really helps,however I have some doubts for this , I have revised my question again , can you please help?

Comment: Could you please provide an example where your `search_analyzer` acts better than original one? BTW, you'd better keep the original answer as well and just add an "Update" section with amendments or even ask a separate question, because otherwise it adds some confusion

Comment: Hi Random ! apologies for late response , but looks like using search_analyzer is also not working consistently, I have updated my question in Update section .It would be great help if you could take a look.

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: Thanks Random , working on it,I would like to confirm one thing, I am indexing my document as 
PUT http://localhost:9200/movies/movie/1
{"title":"$peci@l movie"},

Do I have to use field name also i.e title.en or title.es or title.fr etc. while indexing ?
e.g {"title.en":"$peci@l movie"}

Comment: No, it's enough to put a single value, the mapping will do the rest

Comment: Hi Random ! This satisfies most of my requirements however I am getting some unexpected results for this mapping , I have posted separate question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44515884/elasticsearch-returning-unexpected-results